# Count number of occurences of a value in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that looks like this

```
     email           product_id
nen@something.com        20
nen@something.com        10
nen@something.com        20
nen@something.com        20
nen@something.com        10
```

I want to create a table view that counts the number of times a product is purchased (per email) and display it in one row.

```
     email               product_10       product_20
nen@something.com            2                 3
```

I tried doing it using the following sql, but it did not work.

```
select email,count(product_id) from mytable group by email,product_id;
```

It gave me a table that looked like this.

```
     email           count(product_id)
nen@something.com            2
nen@something.com            3
```

What am I missing here? How can I get the counted products into a single row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use case when

```
     select email, sum(case when productid=10 then 1 else 0 end) as 
     product_10,
     sum(case when productid=20 then 1 else 0 end) as product_20 
     from mytable 
     group by email
```

Comment: What if he has more than 2 products?

Comment: use more conditions

Comment: Thank you sir. This was just what I needed. I was unaware of the `case` condition in postgres. You just saved me a good couple of hours of frustration. Also, the `sum` was very clever. I need to think outside the box more.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Postgres, you can use the `filter` clause.  More elegant and usually a wee bit faster:

```
select email,
       count(*) filter (where productid = 10) as product_10,
       count(*) filter (where productid = 20) as product_20
from t 
group by email;
```

This is ANSI/ISO standard functionality.

Comment: This is definitely more elegant.